# Getting picklist values based on record type for a lightning component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, metadata-api, record-type

Felt like picklists and record types have always been a hassle, not sure if anything has changed recently.

So I am trying to build a 'create new Case' lightning component that is to mimic the VF page and the issue right now is filter the picklist values for a field I got from Schema.getglobaldescribe() based off of record type.

From what I can tell, metadata api is still the only option for this, and there isn't a good path for this through apex, which is an issue because metadata api requires certain permissions?

Anyone find a good solution for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the lightning api [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightningapi.meta/lightningapi/lightning_api_get_started.htm).

[Specifically](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightningapi.meta/lightningapi/lightning_api_resources_picklist_values.htm)

Comment: both links are dead

Answer (score 1):

There's now a good solution: Use Lightning Web Components and the getPicklistValuesByRecordType wire adaptor.

In the spirit of StackExchange, here's the key code:

```
import { getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
export default class PicklistValuesByRecordType extends LightningElement {


@track value;
@track options;

@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: 'Account', recordTypeId: '012B0000000gTUOIA2' }) 
IndustryPicklistValues({error, data}) {
    if(data) {
        this.options = data.picklistFieldValues.Industry.values;
    }
    else if(error) {
        window.console.log('error =====> '+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.value = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

However, credit for this goes to Shaik Nagajani. He has more information [here](https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/12/picklist-values-based-on-recordtype-in-lwc.html).